# iOS Development - How to receive button event from a custom view controller class?

Tags: objective-c, ios, model-view-controller, ibaction

So I've got this "save" button in my main view controller that I would like to move into a different view controller (WriterViewController). After doing this, my custom view controller class isn't able to respond to any of the button events. Not sure what im doing wrong here but here some screenshots:

Save button is first in my main view controller. I'll be moving it to the view controller to the right (WriterViewController).

[image: Save button is currently in the main view controller.]

As you can see, after moving the button into the intended view controller, the view controller has a custom class set to "WriterViewController".

[image]

I then ctrl + click and drag the save button so that i can link up it's "Touch Up Inside" event to the "saveEntry" method.

[image]

A screenshot of my WriterViewController.h file.

[image]

And the implementation.

[image]

Doing the same exact step for the main view controller did work and i was able to log my message. However, it wouldn't work for the custom view controller.

Any thoughts?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just make the save button from scratch for WriterViewController? It's not hard to drag out a UIButton and set it's text to "Save."

Regardless, have you clicked on the button in the scene and viewed the connection's inspector to make sure the connections are what you'd expect? It seems obvious, but sometimes the connections can get all screwed up if you forget to clean them up. (ie. you copy a button over, connections and all, and things don't act as you think they should.)

Comment: That's... odd. It must be something extremely simple and we're missing it. It should be as simple as dragging out the button, setting up the action and connecting it. :| Does the button highlight when you touch it?

Comment: The button highlights but it gets stuck in that state and xcode brings me to this view: http://cl.ly/image/2d0A3o3Y3K1h

Comment: It's a bad access error caused when it reaches lines in the assembly code which are related to pointers and subroutines. There's probably a mismatch between the arguments taken for saveEntry: in your code and the one in the connections area of the button. Ex. if your version takes the _sender_ argument but the method that appears under connections doesn't or the opposite, you'll get this or something similar. The easiest fix is to scrap the method and the button. Drag the button out. Open your .m in an assistant editor. ctrl-drag into the implementation and make the method that way.

Comment: Tried your code and it works fine. So, it's not the code in the screenies that's a problem. It _looks_ like you've got everything hooked up correctly and everything. This one is a stumper. Maybe someone good with assembly code can look at that last screenshot and get a better idea of why/where it's crashing.

Comment: If you're inclined to to look at my source code, the zip file can be downloaded at: http://cl.ly/113F3S0z1s3i. I really appreciate all your help Metabble!

Comment: You're welcome. I know how frustrating it can be to not be able to track down a bug when it should be such a simple thing. I'll look at your source in a minute.

Comment: Alright. I think I isolated the problem. After seeing everything in connections, etcetera working I figured out it's not the target action. The problem is, is that at runtime the view controller instance it sends the message to is invalid, hence the bad access message. The reason? You've probably not implemented your custom segue correctly. Changing the start point of the main storyboard to the one with the screwed up save button makes it work correctly. I have never written a custom segue before, but I'll try to see if I can fix the problem through fixing that. Maybe it's something else, IDK.

Comment: Alright, it does seem to be the segue; embedding the whole thing in a navigation controller and using the normal built-in Push segue works fine. I suggest you do the same. Click the initial scene in the storyboard and go to Editor -> Embed in -> Navigation Controller. Click it. Now, delete your custom segues (just click them in the storyboard and hit delete). Control-drag from the buttons you want to trigger the segue to the destination and choose "Push" from the list. Now try. Works fine. I'll try to figure out what's wrong with your custom segue in the meantime.

Comment: You're trying to always have a navigation bar since your app is nonlinear, so instead of truly segueing you just slap the destination view controller's whole view into the current VC's subviews. This makes target action not work correctly. I don't know if there's a way to do it the way you've done it, but consider using a UITabBarController instead; it's made for this kind of thing. You could also try this: https://github.com/futuresimple/FSVerticalTabBarController if you just _have_ to have a vertical tab bar. Other than tab bars, I don't know how I would implement what you've tried to.

Comment: Metabble, you are truly awesome! Having the custom segue isn't all that important to me. I'm just trying to understand the interaction between interface builder/storyboard and how it gets linked up with the actual code. The FSVerticalTabBarController looks interesting enough. I'll definitely have to give it a try when i'm ready. Anyways, i'll also consider using the UITabBarController for now on. Thank you once again for all of your help!

Comment: You're very welcome. Hopefully you can figure out something that works well for what you want to do. TBH, I never stray much from navigation controllers, tab controllers and the standard segues, so I'm sorry that I didn't know how you would do what you wanted to (be able to take the destination VC's view and kind of embed it in the source VC) without messing up target action.